# Retrieving Hierarchical Data from table for displaying tree structure in ul li tag

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following table :

```
id      name                       lft     rgt     level
---     -------------------------  ----    ----    -----
1       company name                1       16      0
2       HR                          2       3       1
3       Superwiser                  4       9       1
4       Associates                  5       6       2
5       test                        10      13      1
6       test2                       11      12      2
```

Using this database I want to display the tree structure in ul li tag. But not getting this table. I want to display like this:

```
1. Company Name
|--:Hr  
|--:Superwiser  
   |--:Associates  
|--:test  
   |--:test2
```

How can I fire specific query for this and how to display it in ul li tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain your schema for me? Usually in a tree structure, you would normally only have a `ParentID` column that links that row, to the other row it belongs to. If you have this, it doesn't make much sense based on your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
```

class Category
{

```
var $table='';
    var $CI ='';
    var $ul_class='';

    function Category($config=array()){
        $this->table=$config['table'];
        $this->CI=& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $this->ul_class=$config['ul_class'];
    }
    function getTree($parent_id=0){

       $this->CI->db->where('parent_id',$parent_id);
       $first_level=$this->CI->db->get('category')->result();
       $tree= '<ul class="'.$this->ul_class.'">';
       foreach($first_level as $fl){
           $tree.='<li>'.$fl->name;
            $this->CI->db->where('parent_id',$fl->cat_id);

           $count=$this->CI->db->count_all_results($this->table);

           if($count!=0){
               $tree.=$this->getTree($fl->cat_id);
           }
           $tree.= '</li>';
       }
       $tree.= '</ul>';

       return $tree;
    }
```

} 
?>

Use this library

Comment: Can you please clarify the above code that what you did here.

Comment: brother your database structure is wrong.. There should be a parent id on field. I am going to show you an example bellow..

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `top` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `column` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `total_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

This is my database table and i m going to create tree with this table
And here is my function

```
function getTree(){
$config['ul_class']='tree';
$config['table']='category';
$this->load->library('category',$config);
echo $this->category->getTree();
}
```

and library is same

```
<?php
```

class Category
{

```
var $table='';
    var $CI ='';
    var $ul_class='';

    function Category($config=array()){
        $this->table=$config['table'];
        $this->CI=& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $this->ul_class=$config['ul_class'];
    }
    function getTree($parent_id=0){

       $this->CI->db->where('parent_id',$parent_id);
       $first_level=$this->CI->db->get('category')->result();
       $tree= '<ul class="'.$this->ul_class.'">';
       foreach($first_level as $fl){
           $tree.='<li>'.$fl->name;
            $this->CI->db->where('parent_id',$fl->cat_id);

           $count=$this->CI->db->count_all_results($this->table);

           if($count!=0){
               $tree.=$this->getTree($fl->cat_id);
           }
           $tree.= '</li>';
       }
       $tree.= '</ul>';

       return $tree;
    }
```

} 
?>

You have to save this class file inside your library folder in application folder with file name category

Answer (score 0):

Recursive database calls are the sign of the devil, so the way I usually handle this, is using PHP it self.

i.e.

```
function buildTree($ParentID, $Categories, $Output = '')
{
    foreach($Categories as $Category)
    {
        // Skip any categories that are not
        // in the current parent.
        if($Category->ParentID != $ParentID)
            continue;
        // Add the current category to the output
        $Output .= '<li>' . $Category->name . '</li>';
        // If the category has children, recurse another level.
        if($Category->ChildCount > 0)
        {
            $Output .= '<ul>';
            $Output .= $this->buildTree($Category->ID, $Categories, $Output);
            $Output .= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    return $Output;
}
```

Then you would simply call it like:

```
<ul><?= buildTree(0, $Categories); ?></ul>
```

The code relies on you doing a sub-query that returns the count of child rows that belong to that parent row.

i.e.

```
select *, (select count(C2.*) from Category C2 where C2.ParentID = C1.ID) as ChildCount from Category as C1
```

This then allows you to only continue recursing if the parent node actually has children and prevents empty `UL`'s from being added to the output when no children exist.